# How to calculate decimal value?

Tags: solidity

```
function claim() public {
    uint myWai = 10000000000;
    uint totalWei = 20000000000;
    uint myPercentage = myWai/totalWei * 100;

    payable(msg.sender).transfer(12345/100*myPercentage);
}
```

I expect that 'myWay/totalWei' will be '0.5' but actually it return '0'. How to calculate decimal numbers??

My solidity version is 0.8

Comment: Use [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate what percentage a value is of another value you can do the multiplication before the division, you can also multiply by a high number to make sure you avoid underflow.

```
function claim() public {
    uint myWai =    10000000000;
    uint totalWei = 20000000000;
    uint myPercentage = myWai * 1e18 / totalWei; // add 1e18 for granularity

    payable(msg.sender).transfer(12345 * myPercentage / 1e18); // divide by 1e18 to account for added granularity
}
```

In short, always multiply before you divide, and multiply by high enough number so to avoid any unwanted behaviour, then correct it by dividing result with that same number.

Comment: The value will be transfered should be '12345 * myPercentage / 1e18' not '12345/100 * myPercentage / 1e18'. Right?

Comment: oops, yes correct, I accidentally left that there, will update answer 

Answer (score 0):

Solidity support only integer numbers, consequently it doesn't support decimal numbers. This is reason because you see 0 (in your case) when try to execute a division whose result a decimal number. If you want to operate with decimal number you can try to convert these last into integer numbers and operate with them.
More information [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html#fixed-point-numbers).